# ABC is an isosceles triangle with AB = AC = 3. There are k distinct points on BC, denoted by P1, P2, P3...Pk.

Tags: geometry

ABC is an isosceles triangle with AB = AC = 3. There are k distinct points on BC, denoted by P1, P2, P3...Pk. Let Xi = (APi)^2 + (BPi x PiC) where i = 1, 2, 3...k. Find the value of k if X1 + X2 + X3 ... Xk = 1080.

So
$X_i=3^2=9$

$k \cdot 9=1080$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your post would be a lot easier to read if you also used proper formatting on the paragraph. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StewartsTheorem.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solvable because $P_iA^2+BP_i\cdot CP_i=AB^2=AC^2=9$ for every  $i.$

Let $AB=c,\;BC=a,\; CA=b.\;$ For brevity let $P_iB=x_i, \; P_iC=y_i, \; P_iA=z_i,\;$ and  $ \cos B=\cos C=D.$ By the cosine formula we have $$z_i^2=x_i^2+b^2-2x_ibD.$$ $$z_i^2=y_i^2+c^2-2y_icD.$$ Adding these and substituting $b=c=3$ we have $$2z_i^2=x_i^2+y_i^2+18-6(x_i+y_i)D.$$ Adding $2x_iy_i$ and noting that $x_i+y_i=BC=a,$ we have $$2(x_iy_i+z_i^2)=2x_iy_i+x_i^2+y_i^2-6(x_i+y_i)D=(x_i+y_i)^2+18-6(x_i+y_i)D=$$ $$=a^2+18-6aD.$$ By the cosine formula we have $$9=c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos C=a^2+9-6aD,$$ $$\text {So } a^2-6aD=0.$$ $$\text {Therefore }\; 2(x_iy_i+z_i^2)=a^2-6aD+18=18.$$ $$\text {So } x_iy_i+z_i^2=9.$$ $$\text {Finally, }\; 1080=\sum_{i=1}^k(x_iy_i+z^2)=\sum_{i=1}^k9=9k.$$ $$\text {So } k=120.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because according to Stewart's theorem you have
$$X_i = AP_i^2 + BP_i\cdot P_iC=\frac{3^2P_iC+3^2BP_i}{BP_i+P_iC}=9.$$

Comment: Thanks you very much by correction of writing.

Answer (score -1):

Your hypothesis is that $X_i = 9 $ $ \forall i$ but $X_i = (AP_i)^2 + (BP_i)(P_iC)$. So the value of $X_i$ can't be considered as a constant.

For example if you take $B$ like $P_i$, so  $X_i = (AB)^2 + (BB)(BC) = (AB)^2 = 9$.

If you take the mid of $BC$, called $D$, like $P_i$, so  $X_i = (AD)^2 + (DB)(DC) = (AD)^2*(DB)^2 $ .

We can consider a triangle where $BC =4$. So $DB =2$ and  $AD= \sqrt5$ (because $BC^2 + DA^2 = AB^2$ by Pythagorus).

We have :
$X_i = (\sqrt5)^2*(2)^2 = 20$.

And if your $X_i$ are different you can't use your formula ...

Comment: It seems that  the Q was re-written after your A.

Comment: You made an error and replaced plus with times. In your example X = AD^2 + (DB) (DC)=AD^2 + (DB)^2. You wrote times. So X = 5 + 2^2 and not $5*2^2$ which *does* equal 9 and not 20.  Turns out all X_i are constant after all. And no, the question had not been changed since this answer.